# Cannot resolve symbol DrawerLayout

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I'm trying to implement the Navigation Drawer as shown here:  http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#top

My code seems to be ok, and My minimum and target levels in my manifest match the example, but it's telling me it can't find the following three references

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you've already got an older copy of android-support-v4.jar in your libs/ directory of your project, you need to manually copy the new version over the top of it. The SDK Manager won't do that for you.

Comment: Check my answer if you still have problem.

Answer (score 20):

May be you have found your answer but i think its for those who still wants to know. so, here's my answer,

**For Android Studio:**

> First of all you need to add External Jar

- In android studio go to **File**-> **Project Structure** -> **Modules** ->
  **Dependencies** -> **+** symbol -> **Library Dependency**.
- Now search for **support library**. you will find something like this **com.android.support:support-v13**
- Now, select Jar file named **support-v13** (Whatever the version is) and click OK.

Now, you will see, no more errors like this.

**For Eclipse:**

Refer this link, [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046443/android-import-drawerlayout-cannot-be-resolved)

Comment: That fixed it for me. I had added the dependency manually to the gradle file before which did not work. So something else must be happening when adding the dependency via menu. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I know this is a bit old, but do you know why Android Studio doesn't do this automatically?

Comment: Android studio makes it even easier now. When you go to click `+` you will see "Library Dependency" click that and it will show you a menu with the support files.

Comment: @user1971 is correct in Android Studio goto File --> Project Structure --> Modules --> app --> Dependencies --> Click + --> m Library Dependencies. For me I had to add the appcompact v7. As a side note I may encounter this again because I'm developing using material theme which I'm not sure right now is part of appcompact :/

Comment: Thank You very much .. Worked for me.. :)

Answer (score 7):

You need to make sure you are using the latest [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) as the `DrawerLayout` and other items were added in the May 2013 release.

- > Added DrawerLayout for creating a Navigation Drawer that can be
  >   pulled in from the edge of a window.

Comment: Updating it now to see if that's the issue.

Comment: I have all the API's updated an installed from 4.0 (API 14) up and all the extra tools.  I restarted Android Studio and still get the same error.

Comment: If you look in the [SDK manager](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html) you should be able to see your current version and unless it is May 2013 that is your issue. I had to use some `explicit' force a few months back in IntelliJ to force the upgrade.

Comment: I removed it and readded it.  You can see the pictures above.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference the support library in your project dependencies. Import the jar package into your java build path using the Project/Properties/Java Build Path/Libraries tab and use the button 'Add External JARs....'

Now compile the project.

Comment: Is that for Eclipse?  I'm using Android Studio.