# DrawerLayout and ActionBarDrawerToggle cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to implement *ActionBarSherlock Side Menu Navigation Drawer* in my app, but always getting :

> DrawerLayout cannot be resolved to a type ActionBarDrawerToggle cannot be resolved to a type

My **imports** are:

```
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
```

Comment: check out this link. Hope this will help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046443/android-import-drawerlayout-cannot-be-resolved

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Import these from the support library

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
```

Check this

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

For more info on NaigationDrawer

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: I think it's relevant to add that you can use the v4 support library or you can simply copy the `android-support-v13.jar` support library into the /libs folder of your project.

Answer (score 2):

yeah I fully agree with @Raghunandan when we do work with Navigation Drawer, we need to use Latest support Library

And when we do work with ActionBar Sherlock Navigation Drawer, some imports we need to use in our program, see below:

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
```